# Unable to delete data from oracle database using php

Tags: php, html, css, database, oracle

I am using php to delete data from the database but its not deleting and there is no error showing.

*Please help me.*

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $p_No = $_POST['p_No'];
    $sql2 = "DELETE FROM usersR WHERE p_No = '$p_No'";
    $compiled1 = oci_parse($conn,$sql2);
    $ex = oci_execute($compiled1,OCI_DEFAULT);
?>
```

Its my connect.php code

```
 <?php
       $username = "system";
       $password = "******";
       $connectionString = "localhost/ORCL";

       $conn = oci_connect($username, $password, $connectionString);
       if (!$conn) {
          $e = oci_error();
          trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
          }

        ?>
```

Comment: See What Error It's Coming by `if (!$ex) {echo oci_error();}`

Comment: @NanaPartykar no error is coming

Comment: Paste your **connect.php** file too.

Comment: Is the `p_No` column `char` or `num`? If it's `num` remove the single quotes (`'`) around the variable `$p_No`. Also, you're vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/3775731).

Comment: @NanaPartykar done

Comment: @timclutton how i am vulnerable to sql injections

Comment: You clearly haven't read the page I linked to.

Comment: @timclutton i have removed the single quotes but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php):

> OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT:   Do not automatically commit changes. Prior to PHP
>   5.3.2 (PECL OCI8 1.4) use OCI_DEFAULT which is equivalent to OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT.

So, you should be using `OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS` or doing an explicit commit.

To emphasize the comments everyone's made: add error checking and use bind variables to prevent SQL Injection.

When in doubt read the [PHP OCI8 manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) and also the [Underground PHP & Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html), which I keep linking to because it is really a big FAQ.